# prevent duplicate with mysql's COUNT

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have two tables, one with country prefixes, the other with calls made.

prefixes table may look like this:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+
|   id | country   | prefix    |
+------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 |       USA | 1         | 
|    2 |    canada | 1         | 
|    3 |   spain   | 4         | 
+------+-----------+-----------+
```

calls table:

```
+-----------+-------------------+
| id        | destination       |
+-----------+-------------------+
|       1   |                 1 | 
|       2   |                 1 | 
|       3   |                 4 | 
|       4   |              1441 | 
+-----------+-------------------+
```

Im trying to find how many calls made to each country:

```
select count(*) as calls
  from calls as t1
inner join prefixes as t2
  on t1.destination like CONCAT('%', t2.prefix)
```

Problem is USA and Canada has the same prefix, I get double results, I also must work with current tables without adding/editing.

Is it possible to iterate over the calls table, but only  search for each prefix once?

expected result:
3 calls for prefix 1 (USA/CANADA),
1 call for spain.

Comment: With these tables you can't find out how many calls were made to each country by definition as you can't distinguish USA and Canada. So what do you expect as result? 1. Two times USA, once Spain; 2. Two times Canada, once Spain; 3. Once USA, once Canada and once Spain; 4. Something else?

Comment: thanks, added expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach with your exact data would be:

```
select count(*) as calls, t2.country as country
    from calls as t1
left join 
(select group_concat(country) as country, prefix from prefixes group by prefix) as t2
    on t1.destination like CONCAT(t2.prefix, '%')
group by substring(t1.destination,1,1)
```

which results in:

```
| CALLS |    COUNTRY |
|-------|------------|
|     3 | USA,Canada |
|     1 |      Spain |
```

and here you have the corresponding [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29321/45)

This approach should be faster as there are less nested queries.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the last row of your call table. From your expected result I suppose it is a 1 and not a 1441. Try with:

```
select country, n_calls from
(select destination, count(*) as n_calls from calls group by destination ) as a 
left join 
(select group_concat(country) as country, max(prefix) as destination from country group by prefix) as b
on a.destination=b.destination;
```

This give me:

```
 **country**   **n_calls**
  usa,canada      3
  spain           1
```